# Handling staticmethods while working with metaclasses

Tags: python-3.x

In the code below, I am using a metaclass along with a decorator to decorate all the user defined methods.

It works for all instance methods, but in cases of staticmethods it fails due to the self argument, to avoid that I am using a try and except block, which solves the problem. But in one of my projects, it's not working out.

Is there a better way of decorating the output of a staticmethod via a function decorator enclosed in a metaclass ?

```
from functools import wraps
import types

def decorator_function(input_function):
    @wraps(input_function)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get("test_parameter"):
            kwargs["test_parameter"] = 999
        try:
            result = input_function(self, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            result = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper


class DecoratorMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict):
        klass = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict)

        for key in dir(klass):
            value = getattr(klass, key)
            if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType) and "__" not in key:
                wrapped = decorator_function(value)
                setattr(klass, key, wrapped)
        return klass


class InterfaceClass(metaclass=DecoratorMetaClass):
    def function(self, test_parameter=1):
        print(f"function - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")

    @staticmethod
    def static_function(test_parameter=1):
        print(f"static_function - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")


class UserClass(InterfaceClass, metaclass=DecoratorMetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def function_2(self, test_parameter=1):
        print(f"function_2 - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")


instance = UserClass()
instance.function(test_parameter=2)
instance.function_2(test_parameter=2)
instance.static_function(test_parameter=2)
print(isinstance(instance, InterfaceClass))
```

PS: I am not using a class decorator because it causes the isinstance checks to fail.

Comment: You can change the signature of the function `wrapper` from `wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)` to `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`. Then just assign `result = input_function(*args, **kwargs)`. You don't need the try/except block for this decorator.

Answer (score 0):

##### Explanation

The major problem goes down to the methods parameters. You were almost there.

1. You have to make the decorators arguments compatible to your methods parameters;
2. You can change the signature of the function wrapper from `wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)` to `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`. Then just assign `result = input_function(*args, **kwargs)`. *You don't need the try/except block for this decorator*;

```
def decorator_function(input_function):
    @wraps(input_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get("test_parameter"):
            kwargs["test_parameter"] = 999
        return input_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

3. Ideally you should add to the methods `*args` (variable arguments) and `**kwargs` (variable named arguments) to make them compatible with your decorator;
4. In this case I added `*args` before the `test_parameter=1` to the `static_function` in `InterfaceClass`.

```
class InterfaceClass(metaclass=DecoratorMetaClass):
    @staticmethod
    def static_function(*args, test_parameter=1):
        print(f"static_function - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")
```

##### Runnable Code

```
from functools import wraps
import types

def decorator_function(input_function):
    @wraps(input_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get("test_parameter"):
            kwargs["test_parameter"] = 999
        return input_function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


class DecoratorMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict):
        klass = super().__new__(meta, name, bases, class_dict)

        for key in dir(klass):
            value = getattr(klass, key)
            if isinstance(value, types.FunctionType) and "__" not in key:
                wrapped = decorator_function(value)
                setattr(klass, key, wrapped)
        return klass


class InterfaceClass(metaclass=DecoratorMetaClass):
    def function(self, test_parameter=1):
        print(f"function - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")

    @staticmethod
    def static_function(*args, test_parameter=1):
        print(f"static_function - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")


class UserClass(InterfaceClass, metaclass=DecoratorMetaClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def function_2(self, test_parameter=1):
        print(f"function_2 - Test Parameter= {test_parameter}")

instance = UserClass()
instance.function(test_parameter=2)
instance.function_2(test_parameter=2)
instance.static_function(test_parameter=2)
UserClass.static_function(test_parameter=3)
print(isinstance(instance, InterfaceClass))
```

##### Output

```
function - Test Parameter= 999
function_2 - Test Parameter= 999
static_function - Test Parameter= 999
static_function - Test Parameter= 999
True
```

##### Addressing OP's comment

Considering `test_parameter` is always a named parameter, write the `decorator_function` as the following:

```
def decorator_function(input_function):
    @wraps(input_function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get("test_parameter"):
            kwargs["test_parameter"] = 999
        try:
            result = input_function(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            result = input_function(**kwargs)
        return result
    return wrapper
```

This way you don't need to change the methods signature.

If you call the functions also with positional arguments, you will need to check the type of the first argument inserted into `args`. Things get complicated and error prone.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, the reason why I added self was because I wanted to access some instance variables inside the decorator, but I can do that by checking inside the args structure to find the instance reference.

Comment: But is there any other way, which doesn't involve changing the signature of the staticmethod ? Because if I were to use metaclasses with a larger framework, I cannot change the signature of all the staticmethods.

Comment: It's feasible but it is harder for me to know because I don't know how the methods are being called elsewhere (with position or named parameters). If the method is called with positional parameters the value will go to `args`, if called with named parameters `kwargs`. That's one of the reasons `args` and `kwargs` usually should be in the method's signature. At least that's how I think...

Comment: I'm writing a solution to you considering `test_parameter` is always a named parameter...

Comment: I updated my answer. See the **Addressing OP's comment** section...